# Add a MAX aggregation function to a query

Tags: 7, database

I'm building a query with `$query = new db_select('node', 'n')` and I'm grouping by a certain field (let's say `$query->groupBy('title')`), when I'm aggregate another field (such as `$query->addField('n', 'MAX(nid)')`) it gets sanitized into a field called `n.MAXnid` (which crashes with a warning when executed)

How can I add a `n.MAX(nid)` field to my select query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Drupal 7 you should add expression for this.
Read more on [Dynamic queries](http://drupal.org/node/310075) > [Expressions](https://drupal.org/node/1848358)

Answer (score 11):

In your case, the code should be something similar to the following one:

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n')->groupBy('title');
$query->addExpression('MAX(nid)', 'max_nid');
```

You don't use `$query = new db_select('node', 'n')`; [db_select()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database--database.inc/function/db_select/7) already returns an object. If you want to clone that object, you should not invoke `new` on it.

[$query->addExpression()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3a%3aaddExpression/7) returns the alias currently used for the expression you add; it is normally the same alias passed to the method, but it can be different if the alias is already used. In this case, the alias is max_nid if max_nid is not already used, or max_nid_N if the alias is already used; N is an integer that is added to make the alias unique.
Using the alias returned from `$query->addExpression()` is important when a function is altering a query passed from other functions, such as in the case of a query passed to a hook. In this specific case it is not necessary, as the function that is calling `db_select()` is also adding the expression.